# How to change MySQL 'root' password using MySQL v5.7?

Tags: mysql

Current Environment :

```
mysql> show variables like "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.13                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1                |
| version                 | 5.7.13                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Password Change command user :

```
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("XXXX") where user="root";
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: try to start `mysql` under safe mode. then you can change the root password

Comment: To anyone reading this thread. MySQL 5.7 has substantial changes under the hood. Please read about them *before* upgrading.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7, the `password` field in `mysql.user` table field was removed, now the field name is `authentication_string`.

First choose the database:

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

And then show the tables:

```
mysql> show tables;
```

You will find the `user` table, and see its fields:

```
mysql> describe user;
```

You will realize there is no field named `password`, the password field is named `authentication_string`. So, just do this:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('XXXX') where user='root';
```

As suggested by @Rui F Ribeiro, alternatively you can run:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Comment: +1 for the authentication_string reference. I also recently find out about it after upgrading to 5.7

Comment: While it is not directed entirely to this answer, another alternative for 5.7 is `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('new_password');`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks, updated my answer

Comment: Rahul Initially I edited the thread to later than 5.7, but then changed it to using MySQL 5.7, to keep more to the spirit of the question. e.g. @Shivu did not know it is a change in 5.7.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro but OP doesn't even care about what's going on here.

Comment: It is a way of framing the question. We are not editing questions and answers only for the benefit of the OP, but also for others later on.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro that's right

Comment: way to go mysql! such a brilliant idea to break millions of scripts out there in the wild....who needs stupid things like backwards-compatibility anyway?

Comment: @cas I didn't get you

Comment: Tried to look at 'user' table, couldn't relate the change.Thanks @Rahul.

Comment: @ShivuRH did that helped you ? you were able to change root password with this method ?

Comment: @ShivuRH you were not able to change password ?

Comment: @ShivuRH `Query OK, 1 row affected` that means, it has changed root password successfully. Please try to login in mysql with the password which you set.

Comment: `mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('xxxxxxx') where user='root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> \q
Bye`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41550/discussion-between-rahul-and-shivu-rh).

Comment: `set password for...` didn't work for me on OSX but `update user set...` did work.

Comment: @Rahul I tried what's in your answer several times but I still can't login, any ideas?

Comment: @PetarVasilev any error in log file ?

Comment: @Rahul in the log file there is only "Access denied" errors

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL way of changing password is **`SET PASSWORD`**

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

see [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  SET PASSWORD Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html)

> The SET PASSWORD statement assigns a password to a MySQL user
>   account, specified as either a cleartext (unencrypted) or encrypted
>   value:
>
> ```
> 'auth_string' represents a cleartext password.
>
> 'hash_string' represents an encrypted password.
> ```

The accepted answer from Rahul shows how to update password with `DML` statement.

```
update user set authentication_string=password('XXXX') where user='root';
```

Warning: that's not the official and supported way. It can cause troubles, if you don't know what you are doing. Don't forget `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

> For most operations, like creating a user, changing its privileges, or
>   changing its password, you will want to use the high-level statements.
>   Not only they are easier to use and they are compatible with a larger
>   number of MySQL versions, but they will also prevent you from making
>   mistakes (of course, remember to setup the “NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER“ sql
>   mode). They even usually work nicely in a MyISAM-hostile environment
>   like a Galera cluster.

[Stop using FLUSH PRIVILEGES](http://dbahire.com/stop-using-flush-privileges/)

Please use `GRANT`, `REVOKE`, `SET PASSWORD`, or `RENAME USER` and not direct DML statements.

Update: SET PASSWORD ... = PASSWORD('auth_string') syntax is [deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) and will be removed in a future MySQL release.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqladmin -u user-name password -p "oldpassword" "newpass"`

if you can login then try this `""` wont work try `''` single quote

`update user set password=PASSWORD("newpass") where User='ENTER-USER-NAME-HERE';`

Comment: While I do prefer the mysqladmin answer, see Rahul´s answer. Your SQL query is outdated. I corrected the mysqladmin, you were missing the password directive.

Comment: Thanks Ribeiro. I missed `authentication_string`

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
mysql.server start
$ mysql -uroot
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('123456') where User='root';
mysql> exit;
mysql.server restart (if you not restart , connection will not work.)
```

So I think, your update command is right, but you need to restart your mysql server.

Answer (score -1):

For this problem, I used a simple and rude method, rename the field name to password, the reason for this is that I use the mac navicat premium software in the visual operation error: Unknown column 'password' in 'field List ', the software itself uses password so that I can not easily operate.
Therefore, I root into the database command line, run

```
Use mysql;
```

And then modify the field name:

```
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE authentication_string password text;
```

After all normal.